# Duplication of one part to the other side?

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

Is there a way to do this without anything being ruined up?, I have tried extruding the object to look like it were the original, but If I were to do it in a more complex object, I'd have to do everything all over again and vice versa, plus the height and wideness of it can never be truly the same.

Image says that pillar A should be duplicated to other side where it says B.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: does it mean it should be mirrored or just arrayed? could you please draw the result you're expecting?

Comment: The result I am thinking of is the letter H. Mirror probably.

Comment: in Edit mode you can make sure that the origin is at the center of the symmetry then go into the header menu > Mesh > Symmetrize, and make sure that the axis is the right one in the Operator box. Is it what you want?

Comment: No not really, it's just duplicating pillar A to the other side but without spaces in between the bridge of the two.

Comment: so what if you select A, duplicate, move the duplication, snap to the bridge, merge the vertices, make sure that you've deleted the inner face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Mesh > Symmetrize* tool would make it fast but as you don't want to use it:

Enable the *Snap to Vertex* and *Auto Merge* options (in order to snap you don't have to activate the *Snap* tool itself, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> when you'll want to snap):

[image]

Select the left part, duplicate it, snap it to the bridge, the vertices will automatically merge, don't forget to remove the inner face:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that solution.